# How can I make the placeholder text of an html input field editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like this
`<input placeholder="something">`

The default behavior is the placeholder text disappears when the user begins typing. How can I make it so the placeholder becomes the actual content of the field and is editable?

Do I need javascript?

Comment: If it’s a useful placeholder, it’s hardly a useful default value. What are you *really* trying to accomplish? To set a default (initial) value, just use the good old `value` attribute. Then a placeholder would probably be just confusing.

Comment: Why do you want to edit the placeholder value?

Comment: Yep you are right I didn't want a placeholder, I wanted value. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Change** your `placeholder` attribute to a `value` attribute eg:

```
<input value='foo'/>
```

This will make *foo* the default content for the input which will be editable when the user clicks in the field.

Answer (score 3):

you can use value attribute for that:

```
<input placeholder="something" value="something"/>
```

using jquery in runtime:

```
$('inp_selector').val($('inp_selector').attr('placeholder'))
```

Comment: might do jQuery stuff on input focus event

Comment: These are both bad ideas. First, there is never a need for a `value` attribute *and* a `placeholder` attribute. Second, fixing a markup problem with jQuery is never a good idea.

Comment: The first approach is to make placeholder work even if text is completely removed.and I have provided the second idea as OP has tagged with jquery. also its possible that input does not have placeholder by default which is set later on. so user can not set that stuff in the beginning..